# addClass vs attr and creating an ID

Tags: jquery

So what I am reading is that when adding a class to an element without any class already assigned, still use the addClass() method over attr().

For example, using:

```
.addClass('myclass')
```

is more efficient than

```
.attr('class','myclass')
```

I cannot find anything equivalent to addId('myid') for adding id selectors, does it exist or is attr() the best way to add an id selector?

I get that id is unique, the logic behind my question is addClass() is faster than attr().

So my question is if there's a more efficient method for creating an id than attr().

Comment: That's because you only have a single id.

Comment: I totally get that, but the point is it's addClass which is faster, meaning attr is the slower function. Are you saying it's only slower for classes but not ids?

Comment: @Aaron, what benchmarks have you run to prove that `addClass` is faster than `attr`? Which browsers did you check? What bottlenecks were you running performance analysis on? Why does the speed of the function matter for a language that spends most of its time in an idle environment?

Comment: @Aaron the apparent difference in run-time is probably negligible for the efficiency of an application. However, you should be concerned about the difference of the behavior as described by the answers below.

Comment: @ShamimHafiz I completely understand the difference in behaviour, wasn't what my question asks for thanks :)

Comment: @Aaron, looks like `attr` is faster than `addClass` to me.

Comment: @zzzzBov if you read a bit online, you will see many sources say addClass is faster than attr.

Comment: My test shows that `attr()` is almost 50% faster than `addClass()`. http://jsperf.com/addclass-performance. But it probably depends on the starting conditions (in my test, the elements don't have a class to start with, so the two functions have the same effect).

Comment: @Aaron, "read a bit online" as in read some articles (which you have not cited)? I ask because real data beats articles always. The jsperf you provided disproves your own statement.

Comment: I'm guessing the answer is going to be 'no, there isn't any more efficient way of adding id selectors'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering directly

> No, **`addId()`** does not exist and **`addClass()`** is not as same as `attr()`

In HTML, a `class` attribute can hold more than one value like `<div class="tall fat brown">Someone</div>` so jQuery's function `addClass()` helps to add a value to the class attribute not change it. Similarly the functions `toggleClass()` and 'removeClass()` help manipulate them.

But the function `attr()` will just manipulate the attribute and change it directly.

For example:

```
<div id="person">someone</div>
```

And the following jQuery Statements

```
$("#div").addClass("tall"); // This will create the class attribute and add tall 
$("#div").addClass("fat");  // This will append fat to the existing class and make "tall fat"
$("#div").addClass("brown"); // likewise
```

`.addClass()` will just append the class name. If same needs to done by using `attr()` you have to do

```
$("#div").attr('class', 'tall');
$("#div").attr('class', 'tall fat');
$("#div").attr('class', 'tall fat brown');
```

Or, you can modify the attribute using

```
$("#div").attr('class', function(i, className) {
    return className + " brown";
});
```

Where as `id`s have one value that needs to be modified or altered so a function like `addId()` would do exactly which attr('id', 'idvalue') would do.

Comment: Well, sort of, but with `attr()` you could also do `$('#div').attr('class', function(i,c){ return c + ' brown'; });` (as an alternative to the last line of the `attr()` code-block). So you don't need to explicitly know, in advance, what the pre-existing values are.

Comment: One important difference between `.addClass()` and modifying the class attribute string yourself with `.attr()` is that `.addClass()` will ensure that the there are no duplicated class names (i.e. "tall fat fat brown tall brown" will collapse to just "tall fat brown").

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of `.addClass()` is different from `.attr()`.

With `.addClass()` you can add existing class to the ones previously added, however `.attr()` will overwrite existing classes.

Also, each element has just one id, therefore it doesn't make sense to provide a way to add another with a function like `addId()`.

Answer (score 0):

Add class will make sure to **appends the className**

But

`.attr('class','myclass')`  overwrites the existing classes with `myclass`

```
<div class="a b c"> </div>

$('a.div').addClass('myclass');
```

Your div will look like this

```
<div class="a b c myclass"> </div>
```

But if your add it as an attribute, it will overwrite the other classes

```
$('a.div').attr('class', 'myclass');

   <div class="myclass"> </div>
```

So now you cannot select the element with `$('div.a')` since that div no longer has the class in question..